# How can I connect a SQL database to a webhosted site with IIS on the web?

Tags: sql, asp.net, database

I am building a test web application in asp.net core and I have hosted my site from laptop. Everything seems good but when I go to access any database related page the page just loads for a bit until it gives me an error and prompts me to go developer mode to see more relevant information(which I can't because the site is not on localhost it is on the web). I tried to change my connection string to different iterations it did not work, the site works locally with IIS express. Frankly I do not know what to do the documentation seems to be not existent so I would appreciate your help. You can test the website at http://digital60.ddnsking.com/.

The connection string in use is:

```
"ConnectionStrings" : {
   "Default": "Data Source=DESKTOP-BULSITK\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TimsDinerDB;Integrated 
    Security=True;Connect 
Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
}
```

The database related pages are Create Order, List Foods, List Orders

This setup as mentioned previously works locally but when I host my site on the web it just does not connect, the hosting occurs from laptop in both cases(no change of OS or hardware on anything). I cannot post all the code of the test site here but if it is necessary I could put all the code in github, but I do not thing this is the problem.

Comment: The Windows-based web server is **IIS** - the "ISS" is the International Space Station - and I don't think you can host your apps there just yet ...

Comment: well I think I have, can you not access http://digital60.ddnsking.com/ ? Sorry for the typo I will try to edit it

Comment: What do your mean with _the hosting occurs from laptop in both cases_ Are you telling us that IIS on your laptop is used to host a site reachable from Internet? Or are you uploading your app to some Hosting provider that publish your work on internet?

Comment: no I mean that IIS is hosting the site to the web(I have used port forward to do that). IIS express is hosting the site locally when I test it(on localhost). Yes I am telling you that the IIS on my laptop is used to host a site reachable from the internet. If you have any problems accessing my site you could tell me , I have tested it from my phone and it works for me(4G).

Comment: Perhaps is just a matter of permissions. When your site tries to connect to the database it will do it using the default account defined by IIS .  _IUSR_ and this one should have the permissions to read/write your db

Comment: Well how do I interact with the default account which is defined by IIS? Could you tell me where the settings are so I can change them. I will try to google it myself thought :D.

Comment: I have added the IUSR account and I have also given the website the permissions to modify read and write and still nothing. I also restarted the webserver and the site to make sure the changes applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a lot of hours I fixed it, I am not exactly certain what fixed it but I believe it was probably my changes on the connection string,
So the final connection string was:

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
"Default": "Server=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=TimsDinerDB;User Id=sa;Password=[Password];Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"}
}
```

you have to first activate the sa(server administrator) user from sql server for this one to work, and fill the password with the password you add to the sa user. I will try to see if it can be done with other users too. Other change I made was in security to add the IUSRS permissions to read write and modify but I am not certain if that was necessary.

Comment: it works with other users too , you do not need the sa user. The issue I had was that it does not seem to work with windows integrated security, the word Server might have actually made a difference but I will leave it as it is, I hope that people will not have to suffer as I have for this simple tweak :D.

Comment: Using a sql logon would have been the FIRST suggestion I would had made here. When you run local, then your laptop is a admin, and can connect to the database. When you connect from OTHER then your laptop, then the connection string to the SQL server is NOT considered a local admin user and thus resolution of the windows logon to sql server can't occur. So, by adopting a sql logon, then that logged on user to the web site does not have to be part of your company network. So, if you added several more computers to your home network, then only the main computer has rights to sql server.

Comment: Other people on your network can't use the admin local rights to sql server. and you not running a local domain server anyway. (a domain server is what lets you set rights and what user belongs to what security group - that information is used to connect to sql server. So, if you specify a sql logon in place of a "domain" or so called windows auth user, then windows networking security is not used for who has and can connect to sql server.

Comment: I am a bit confused what do you mean by logon? Is it adding a user/login in SQL server as I did? Sorry if this is trivial I am just experimenting with these stuff. I also did not know what a domain server is , I know what a domain name server is(dns) but if this is what you are referring to I think that domain name server is a server that makes an IP into a domain name of the users choosing, have I gotten something wrong? Based on what you are writing they are a different thing and they just sound different , I will google it for more info.

Comment: yes - you have two types of sql server logons systems. You can use windows authentication. When you choose that option then the logon from windows OS is used. Obviously when on a network, then you have to be using a system setup for windows logons. A lot of companies use windows logons, since then they have one central system to control and manage windows logons (its called a domain server - and that server thus can change passwords, and manage all computers on the network. And SQL server can also use that system. Now on a single user system, windows authentication is only you the admin.

Comment: So you the sole computer user is the "admin" of that system, and thus you are able to connect to sql server that way. Anyone else on your network (which you don't have) would have to be granted permissions from that domain control computer, and the rights to sql server thus come from that domain controller server.  However, you ALSO choose to use a SQL server logon. SQL logons now ignore and does not use the window domain server + logon system.  So you as the sole user on that computer could always connect to SQL server - but not any other computer on the network - include the IIS users.

Comment: And you find the same for say a hosted internet plan. They can't make you or the web site a whole admin user, so in most cases you don't even have a domain controller, and thus you have no other choice then to use SQL logons. Keep in mind that IIS also supports domain logons if you have implemented IIS security. That allows anyone on the corporate network with a valid windows logon to log into the web site and in turn also control who can connect to sql server. As noted it thus makes most sense to not use windows authenctaion to connect to sql server when not on a corporate network + domain.